# UILabel apply transform and set layout constraints

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uilabel, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to rotate a UILabel using this code,

```
self.itemlistLabel.text = "Playlist"
self.itemlistLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2)
```

This rotates the label, but this is not setting the label correctly inside the view, I have added a blue background colour to the label,

[image]

This is the screenshot from Xcode with the layouts set, but after applying transform this is not displaying as expected. How to fix this?

[image]

This is the final view, I am trying to make,
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "as expected"? What behavior do you expect?

Comment: Try to set self.itemlistLabel.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1) or self.itemlistLabel.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0) and check difference.

Comment: @ZGl6YXNt I tried both, but that shifted the label to left and the second one to top, I added the expected view. Thanks for your help.

Comment: 1) Apply transform to layer: self.itemlistLabel.layer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2))
2) Add proper constraints. You need to swap width and height:
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    self.itemlistLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelSuperview.centerXAnchor),
    self.itemlistLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelSuperview.centerYAnchor),
    self.itemlistLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelSuperview.heightAnchor),
    self.itemlistLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelSuperview.widthAnchor),
])